# How do I make Tkinter drawing lines from an x interval and a y NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tkinter, line

I have two sources of data to be plotted as X and Y coordinates on a continuous Tkinter line. The x data is generated from a constant like say 1.3. So each x value has to be + 1.3 greater than the last - for example 3.9, 5.2, 6.5 and so on. The y values are held in a numpy array. I need to create a line on a canvas according to these two sets of data.

I have a feeling that this is so, so easy and I am missing something really stupid. So, apologies if this is the case.

At the moment I generate the line array using a for loop but it is too slow (I need to do loads of these per second).

```
x_start = 3
x_stop = 5
step = 1.3

for n in range(x_start, x_stop):
    x = n * step
    line_array[n * 2] = x
    line_array[n * 2 + 1] = array[n]
```

Comment: I don't really understnd the question. What is a "continuous Tkinter line" and how much data do you have? Are you trying to make a histogram?

Comment: By a continuous line I mean what a mathematician would call a continuum comprising multiple segments. A set of x, y data pairs ordered by the x dimension thereby forming a line with many points as if drawn from an unknown function y = f(x). The amount of data is from three x, y point pairs to as many pairs as there is memory to hold. Typically a few hundred to a few thousand pairs. Am I trying to plot a histogram? No.

Comment: You can use `canvas.create_line(line_array)` to draw the required lines where `canvas` is an instance of `Canvas`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `Canvas.create_line(...)` with the array of points created from your two sources of data as below:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy.random

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, bg='white', width=1600, height=800)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

y_array = numpy.random.randint(100, 700, 5000) # generate 5000 y values

x_start = 3
x_stop = 5000
step = 1.3

# create the array of points and draw them
line_array = [(n*step, y_array[n]) for n in range(x_start, x_stop)]
canvas.create_line(line_array)

root.mainloop()
```

It takes less than a second to draw the lines in my i7 notebook.

Comment: Thank you very much that [(n*step, y_array[n]) for n in range(x_start, x_stop)] function works.